# Transfer most recent commit to another branch

Tags: git

I had created an extra branch for some testing purpose.

Before starting to work, I switched back to master branch and, after having a tea, I started adding files and modifying some other files in master branch.

Only after I committed, I remembered that I was in master branch, while I had to switch to my second-branch before starting the changes.

could you let me know if it is possible to send this commit to the second-branch and remove it from master branch?

thanks

Comment: Please take a backup before trying this (not 100% sure): `git reset --soft HEAD^`, `git checkout second-branch`, and `git commit`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understood you right you can do such things:

```
git checkout master
git log
now check hash commit you want to move - for example: 0123456
git checkout branch
git cherry-pick 0123456
git checkout master
git revert 0123456
```

that's all.

Comment: Note that this will let you pick out a commit that's not at the "tip of a branch", and then revert it (so it's a more general answer than mine).  My answer, with the rollback `git reset` step, is specifically for "you made a commit at the tip of the wrong branch".

Comment: I have a commit that I need to discard. The commit is available only in Local Machine yet and not on remote. I tried this and have 2 commits on master now. whereas I would like master to have none of these commits. Any idea, how do I go about this?

Answer (score 8):

The answer to the question is "sort of, but maybe you don't have to".

To *copy* a commit, use `git cherry-pick commit`.  This essentially tells git: "Go look at the commit I've asked you to cherry-pick.  Whatever changes it made, make those same changes again, on the current branch.  Then make a new commit<sup>1</sup> with the same commit message."

Thus, if you've already made a commit on `master` and you want it on `newbranch` instead:

```
$ git checkout newbranch
$ git cherry-pick master
```

At this point, you'll be on `newbranch` and the commit will have been copied.  You now need to do something about the old commit on `master`.

If you have not published (pushed, or let someone else pull) this commit anywhere, you need only "roll it back":

```
$ git checkout master
$ git reset --hard HEAD^  # be careful here! I always run "git status" first
```

Note that `git reset --hard` will wipe out any in-progress work.

If you *have* published the commit, you generally should revert it instead (see [user2699113's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21656411/1256452)).  A "revert" is a lot like a cherry-pick, copying a commit, except that it *reverses the changes*: whatever was added then is removed now, and whatever was removed, is added back.  (And, as with cherry-pick, revert will auto-commit unless you tell it not to.)

(Note that you can specify a commit by SHA-1 ID, but if there's a name—branch or tag name, or other reference name—for it, you can just write the name.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Unless you use `-n` or `--no-commit` to suppress it, or git is not able to make the same changes and tells you that there was a conflict and makes you fix it up yourself.

---

#### What's this about the "maybe you don't have to" part?

Here's a thing about git and its commits and branches.  Git is different from most other version-control systems, in that while you do a commit "on a branch", the branch *name* is not actually part of the commit.<sup>2</sup>  *You* assign branch *names* (or labels, whatever you want to call these), but the actual branch *structures*—the "structural branches"—are formed by each commit's history.

When a commit is made, that commit records its parent-commit(s).  Branch names are just labels, that give you (and git) a place to start, and then git follows the commit parent IDs.  This means we can draw the commit graph (the directed acyclic graph or DAG of commits) by hand:

```
A <-- B <-- C     <-- master
            ^
             \
              D   <-- branch
```

Here commit `D` is the tip of branch `branch`, and it points back to commit `C` as its parent.  Commit `C` points back to `B`, which points to `A`, which is the initial (root, parent-less) commit.

When you are "on branch master" and make a new branch, that just makes a new *label* that points to the same place you are now.  So suppose you had `A` through `C` before (I won't draw these with as many arrows this time; just assume arrows generally point leftwards):

```
A - B - C      <-- HEAD=master
```

This time I added the `HEAD=` to show how git keeps track of which branch you're "on".  (The `HEAD` file in the `.git` directory just contains the name of the branch: `cat .git/HEAD` and you generally see `ref: refs/heads/master` or whatever.)  If you now do `git checkout -b branch` you get this:

```
A - B - C      <-- master, HEAD=branch
```

(now `.git/HEAD` contains `branch` instead of `master`).

When you make a new commit (any new commit, including the ones from cherry-pick and revert), git looks at `HEAD` to see which branch you're on, and what that branch has for its SHA-1 ID.  That's the "tip of the branch".  Git then makes a new commit whose parent is the old branch-tip, and writes the new commit ID into the branch file, so that the branch name points to the new commit.  (And of course `HEAD` still just has the branch name in it.)

So, if you're "on branch `branch`" and make a new commit `D`, this is what you get:

```
A - B - C      <-- master
          \
            D  <-- HEAD=branch
```

If you goof it up a bit though, and are "on branch `master`", you get this instead:

```
A - B - C      <-- branch
          \
            D  <-- HEAD=master
```

But wait, that's just what you wanted, except for the branch labels.  All you need to do is make the name `master` point where `branch` does, and `branch` point where `master` does, and also switch `HEAD` so that it says `branch` instead of `master`.

As it turns out, that's easy ... well, *pretty* easy. :-)  You need a temporary name since git won't let you have two branches with the same name.  First, rename the branch `branch` to let you change `master`.  Then rename `master` to `branch`, and rename `branch`'s new name to `master`:

```
$ git branch -m branch temp
$ git branch -m master branch
$ git branch -m temp master
```

The first step changes the label `branch` to `temp`.  The second changes `master` to `branch` (and you're still on it, so rewrites `HEAD` too).  The last one changes `temp` to `master`, giving you the commit DAG and label setup you wanted originally.

As with the other section, you should only attempt this kind of "label swapping" on *unpublished* (un-pushed) commits.  (The reason for this is simple enough: when you publish commits, you do it by *name-to-commit-ID mapping*.  If you shuffle labels around and "re-publish", the commit IDs do not change but the name-to-ID mappings do, so anyone who picked up your previous advertising, that `master` meant `bb71dde...` for instance, now gets a new mapping that is not "fast-forward related" to the old one.  People, and git, expect branch mappings to change, but usually only "fast-forward style".)

---

<sup>2</sup>For instance, in Mercurial, the branch name is actually recorded inside the commit-data.

Comment: very nice answer! However, does the branch label swap trick work in case the modifications have already been pushed? I'm afraid it would mess up with the commit history.

Comment: If pushed/published, then no, you don't want to do that!  Well, not unless everyone who works with you on the published commits is OK with it. :-)

Comment: @GabrielePetronella: the "point of no [polite] return" is "publication" not "pushing"; of course, in many cases these two events coincide, but not always; if, for example, you do a `push` to repository that only you have access to, then it's fine to write over it with a subsequent `push -f...`.

Comment: @kjo agreed. From a "don't make your collegues hate you" point of view it makes sense.

Comment: I thought the answer to "but maybe you don't have to" was going to be: If you just made a commit, but to a wrong branch, the stuff you just committed (and that you now desire to commit to a different branch) is still in your working directory.  So another, perhaps more straightforward fix is to do a `git reset HEAD^`, *without* the `--hard`, followed by the commit you meant to make.  (I think.  I'm still learning this stuff.  I might post this as a separate answer.)

Comment: @SteveSummit: That *could* be OK, but remember: what's in your index (or staging area) is still a *snapshot*. So it's based on whatever commit you had checked out, if you reset `--soft`. If you reset with the default `--mixed`, your index has been reset as well, to the commit you just moved-to. It helps to think of everything as a snapshot at all times: any diffs you see are dynamically generated right then, by you calling for them with `git diff` or `git status` (status = run diff twice).

Comment: Yes, I get (or am slowly getting the full implications of) the "everything's a snapshot" part.  And by "reset without --hard, and recommit", I meant, "reset with --mixed, and redo some number of add's, and commit".  Whether it might be safe to actually do a soft reset, and skip the re-adds, was a decidedly edgier question which I was still very much on the fence about.

Comment: @SteveSummit: Note that in less-leaky-abstraction version control systems (e.g., Mercurial), the snapshot vs delta duality is less stark, as it were, since you never get to see any of the *internal* format items. But Git is kind of loud and proud about its index. You are, in effect, forced to learn Git-as-a-file-system to use Git as a VCS.