# Move most recent commit to a different existing branch

Tags: git, branch

I just committed some changes to a feature branch, but I realize I was on the wrong branch.

How do I take the last commit I made, and move it to a different, already existing, branch? I haven't pushed anything yet.

I've seen some similar questions but they all involve creating a new branch, and all the hard head resetting they're doing is a mite scary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transfer most recent commit to another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656309/transfer-most-recent-commit-to-another-branch)

Answer (score 3):

```
git checkout whereishouldhaveputit
git cherry-pick whereididputit
git checkout -B whereididputit whereididputit~
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to really understand that git commits are never 'on' branches. In git, a branch is just a label that points to a single commit, the head of the branch.

So, if you committed to the wrong branch, you need to move the label back to where it was, which is the essence of a reset operation. That will undo your mistake from the point of view of the incorrect place you put the commit. The extra commit will just hang around, doing no harm, until it gets garbage-collected.

Thus, the basic plan would be to use a merge to apply the change as the successor to the head of some other branch, and then do a hard reset to put the label of the accidental target back to where it was.

Comment: there are older commits on wrongbranch that I don't want on rightbranch so I can't just merge wrong into right.  Do I want `cherrypick` ?

Comment: then you want cherrypick to move to the right branch and  git revert, which creates a new commit that undoes an old commit, on the wrong one.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to use reset on your current branch - that's just how this works. Don't worry though - all your stuff will be safe by the time you use it.

First, while on your branch where you've accidentally added the commits (we'll call it `branch1`) create a new branch (let's call it `temp`)

```
git branch temp
```

As @bmargulies said, branches are just a reference to a commit. As long as you have a reference to a commit, you haven't lost it. We're going to move your `branch1` branch back to where it started before you mistakenly made the commits, and so `temp` is our reference to the commits you've added - think of it as a backup. We can now make all sorts of changes to where `branch1` points without worrying about losing your new commits.

If `A`, `B` and `C` were commits originally on `branch1` and you accidentally added `D` `E` and `F` then your commit history will now look something like the following (brackets show which commit each branch is referencing):

```
A <- B <- C <- D <- E <- F (temp)(branch1)
```

If you added, say, 3 extra commits (`D`, `E` and `F`) that you didn't mean to add to `branch1`, then you can reset `branch1` back to where it should be using:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~3
```

Now things will look like this:

```
A <- B <- C (branch1)<- D <- E <- F (temp)
```

Now the scary part. Rebasing. Rebase has a flag --onto which takes the following form:

```
git rebase --onto <branch a> <branch b> <branch c>
```

What it basically says is "find the common ancestor of `branch b` and `branch c`, take the changes introduced by each commit between the common ancestor and `branch c` and replay them onto `branch a`.

The "common ancestor" stuff might sound scary, but if `branch b` is an ancestor of `branch c` (read: arrows point from `branch c` to `branch b`) then the commit `branch b` points to is the common ancestor.

See where this is going? If we say the branch you want to move your commits onto is called `branch2` then you can move the new commits to it using:

```
git rebase --onto branch2 branch1 temp
```

That will take commits `D`, `E` and `F` and put them on the end of `branch2` (they'll be called something else though as this is a rebase - you've said you haven't pushed to a public repo so this shouldn't be a problem)

`branch1` will now be where it was before you mistakenly added those commits, the new commits will be sitting on the end of `branch2`, and you can delete `temp` using

```
git branch -D temp
```

Comment: Just saw you said you only had one commit you wanted to move. Cherry pick will work fine for one commit. Rebasing is overkill.