# Can I move pushed commits from one branch to another existing branch?

Tags: git, git-branch

I have 3 branches: `develop`, `feature-1` and `feature-2`. I was working on `feature-1`, then switched to work on `feature-2`. I then finished work on `feature-2`, committed and pushed to the repo, then created a merge request for that feature. I then saw that `feature-2` contained some commits that were supposed to be in `feature-1`. Can I move them from `feature-2` to `feature-1` locally, then have the same moves reflected in the repo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move a commit to a different branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187442/move-a-commit-to-a-different-branch)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In git, how do I remove a commit from one branch and apply it to a different branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773731/in-git-how-do-i-remove-a-commit-from-one-branch-and-apply-it-to-a-different-bra)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`git cherry-pick <commit-id>` is your friend dear.

1. Go on feature-2 branch
2. Copy `commit-id(s)` you want to move from `feature-2` to `feature-1`
3. Switch to feature-1 branch
4. Now cherry pick all the commits you have copied in step-2 above.

   `git cherry-pick <commit-id>`

   In case you have more than one commits to be moved to `feature-1` then put all the commit-ids in sequence of their commit date/time.

   **For example:**

   `git cherry-pick <commit-id-1> <commit-id-2> . . <commit-id-n>`

Comment: technically you do not *move* the commit, you create a new one with the same content and git remembers this copy when merging.

Comment: @curiousManish Thanks. And when I've moved the commits, will `git push` show the same changes in the repo?

Comment: yep @GluePear .

Answer (score 20):

Your question says that the commits in question belong *in `feature-1` and not in `feature-2` branch*.  The accepted answer does not accomplish this.

`cherry-pick` is an ok way to create a new commit on one branch that duplicates the changes made by a commit on another branch; but it doesn't change the other branch.

So for instance, if you started with

```
x <--(master)
|\
| A1 -- A2 <--(feature_1)
 \
  B1 -- A3 -- B2 <--(feature_2)
```

where `A3` was meant for `feature_1`, after following a `cherry-pick` procedure you will have

```
x <--(master)
|\
| A1 -- A2 -- A3' <--(feature_1)
 \
  B1 -- A3 -- B2 <--(feature_2)
```

So `feature_1` may look like you want it now, but `feature_2` still has some changes it presumably shouldn't have.  It's possible that this will cause some trouble when you merge both features into `master`.  (By that I mean, there may be merge conflicts that don't make much sense.  `git` does try to help out here, but it can't be perfect.)

In your question you note that the commits were already pushed, and in response to the `cherry-pick` answer, you ask if the changes will `push` cleanly; so I assume you've run into (at least some of) the problems with rewriting history on a branch you've pushed.

While it's true that the results of the `cherry-pick` will `push` cleanly, that's because the `cherry-pick` didn't make all the changes you've asked for (as noted above).  It's the fix to `feature-2` that really causes a problem with `push`.

One solution is to use `cherry-pick` to fix `feature-1`, then use `revert` to fix `feature-2`.  In our example, using `feature-2~1` as an expression that identifies the commit to be "moved" (you could generally use the commit ID, or an expression appropriate to your real situation):

```
git checkout feature-1
git cherry-pick feature-2~1
git checkout feautre-2
git revert feature-2~1
```

gives you

```
x <--(master)
|\
| A1 -- A2 -- A3' <--(feature_1)
 \
  B1 -- A3 -- B2 -- !A3 <--(feature_2)
```

This will still `push` cleanly (because no commit was removed from any branch's history) and both branches will have the right changes now.  On the plus side, this makes it less likely that you'd have any merge issues; on the down side, certain `rebase` operations could now be problematic.  There are steps you might take to mitigate that, but if you're worried about only making changes that `push` cleanly, then you won't be doing that sort of `rebase` anyway.

If there are many commits you want to "move", then you might want to replace the `cherry-pick` with an interactive `rebase`, like this:

```
git checkout feature-2
git branch temp
git rebase -i feature-1 temp
```

An editor will open, showing a "todo" list for `rebase`.  Each entry on the list is the instruction for how to handle a commit.  Delete the lines for commits you want to "leave behind".  (There are other tweaks you could make to how the commits will be represented on `feature-1`; but that's a long rabbit hole since all you've asked so far is how to "move" the commits, so just these steps will keep them "as is".)

When you save and exit the editor, the `rebase` will commence, rewriting all of the selected commits.  Finish up the update to `feature-1` by

```
git checkout feature-1
git merge temp
git branch -d temp
```

You'll still need to go to `feature-2` to revert the commits that shouldn't be there; you might want to do that in a single command with the `-n` flag, so that you can create just a single revert commit.  (This will have the side-effect of reducing the risk I noted above, of certain `rebase` operations acting up after you do the `revert`; but again, I expect you won't be doing those types of `rebase` anyway given the constraints implied by this question.)

Now some people don't love using `revert` for this kind of thing, because the history shows what happened - including making the changes and later removing the changes, which may seem annoying since the change should never have been made.

The only way to avoid that is to "rewrite the history" of `feature-2`, and no matter how you do it, that will not `push` cleanly.  You can *get* it to `push`, but in so doing you'll create work for all the other developers who have a copy of `feature-2` - and if they do the wrong thing, it will undo your work.  So you have to coordinate with everyone else who uses the repo if you want to do a history rewrite.  See the `git rebase` docs under "recovering from upstream rebase" for more information about this.