# How to rebase diverged Git branches in chronological order?

Tags: git

I was working on my `dev` branch, then made some commits (`A`, `B`, `C`). I switched to the `main` branch for some reason at this point, did edits on different parts of the same files I worked on before (the reason why I didn't notice that I'm on a different branch), then commited `D`...

```
* (4th) D (HEAD -> main)
|
|  * (3rd) C (dev)
|  * (2nd) B
|  * (1st) A
| /
|/
* x
* y
* z
```

What is the most straightforward way to have `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` on one branch (doesn't matter if it's `main` or 'dev`) in the same order they have been created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `main` you can just run `git rebase dev`. That will replay everything you have in `main` which isn't also in `dev` (just `D` according to your diagram) onto the tip of `dev`.

Your `main` branch will then be in the state you want and your `dev` branch will be unchanged.

Comment: That was my first thought, but then I convinced myself that `A`, `B`, and `C`, will be put on top of `D` for some reason... Thanks!

Comment: You'd get that if you ran `git rebase main` from `dev`.

Comment: Yeah, will have to find a mnemonic to remember the right orders.

Comment: @toraritte The **real** solution is to **NEVER** run rebase with less than two arguments (`git rebase onto_ref branch_to_be_rebased`). So `git rebase dev main`will always, unconditionally put `main` on top of `dev` regardless of which branch was current.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
git switch main # start at D
git branch temp # give D a name
git reset --hard @~1 # point main to x
git rebase --onto dev main temp # copy D to after C
git branch -M dev # rename D dev
```

Result:

```
   * (4th) D (HEAD -> dev)
   * (3rd) C
   * (2nd) B
   * (1st) A
  /
 /
* x -> main
* y
* z
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) to move commit `D` from `main` to `dev` by doing the following:

0. Find and copy the commit hash of `D`
1. `git checkout dev`
2. `git cherry-pick <D_COMMIT_HASH>`
3. Resolve the conflicts
4. `git add <AFFECTED_FILES>`
5. `git cherry-pick --continue`

   > At this stage, the commit history looks like the graph below,
   >
   > ```
   > * (4th) D (main)
   > |
   > |  * (new) C_MERGED_WITH_D (HEAD -> dev)
   > |  * (3rd) C 
   > |  * (2nd) B
   > |  * (1st) A
   > | /
   > |/
   > * x
   > * y
   > * z
   > ```
   >
   > because "*[technically you do not **move** the commit, but create a new one with the same content, and `git` remembers this copy when merging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50391577/can-i-move-pushed-commits-from-one-branch-to-another-existing-branch#comment87799160_50391650)*", so:
6. `git checkout main`
7. `git reset --hard HEAD~1`